# How do i add (add all function) on combobox mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

My function to pass roles to combobox in the custom form layout where the combobox is defined

```
   private List<Role> GetRoles()
    {
        return db.Roles.ToList();
    }

        //this will pass a list of roles to the front end
        ViewData["Roles"] = GetRoles();
```

Custom form layout this combox will then load a list of roles from the database table

```
 @Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(ComboBoxsettings =>
            {
                Gsettings.Name = "Id";
                ComboBoxsettings.Name = "RoleId";
                ComboBoxsettings.Width = 500;
                ComboBoxsettings.SelectedIndex = 1;
                ComboBoxsettings.Properties.TextField = "Name";
                ComboBoxsettings.Properties.ValueField = "Id";
                ComboBoxsettings.Properties.DropDownStyle = 
                DropDownStyle.DropDown;
                ComboBoxsettings.ShowModelErrors = true;
            }
      ).BindList(ViewData["Roles"]).Render();
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I think `BindList(ViewData["Roles"])` just enough to pass your list, what's exactly happen on model binding?

Comment: i want to have a method on my controller that will just add all the item in the combobox with a click of a button